# Angular 5 dart translate directive messages

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular-components

I use:

```
  angular: 5.0.0-alpha+13
  angular_components: 0.9.0-alpha+12
```

How can I translate numberIsNotPositiveMsg to anothe language for [PositiveNumValidator](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/lib/material_input/material_number_validators.dart) directive?

Comment: numberIsNotPositiveMsg is already configured for translation using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/intl. Are you asking how to use pkg:intl?

Comment: Yes,maybe  some example use intl with angular.

Comment: With material-input for required field I can use requiredErrorMsg. What I can use with checkPositive?